where should I add .disconnect()?
First time using mutation observer, tried to add disconnect() but seems not working. Need some advice. Thanks.
const targetEl = document.querySelector('.swiper-container');
const cbMutate = (mList) => {
  mList.forEach(
    (rec) => {
      if (jQuery('.item2').length === 1) {
        obsTargetEl.disconnect();
        changeItem();
      }
    }
  );
}

const obsTargetEl = new MutationObserver(cbMutate);
obsTargetEl.observe(targetEl, {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
});


Assuming you want to stop after finding .item2 you should call obsTargetEl.disconnect() before changeItem(); and also remove mList.forEach because you're not actually using the enumeration i.e. just leave the if check.

"tried to add disconnect() but seems not working" - you need to show us what exactly you tried, otherwise we can't help find or fix the problem!

Shouldn't you search for .item2 only within targetEl? And why are you using jQuery for this?

@Bergi I have added disconnect() above but changeItem() is not activated with it

@woxxom thanks, I have tried to call obsTargetEl.disconnect() before changeItem(); but changeItem() does not run after

This is something that you can see in a matter of seconds by debugging the code. Set a breakpoint inside cbMutate and look what happens when it runs. Does the breakpoint even trigger? If not, there's no mutation in the target element. Remove mList.forEach( (rec) => {

"I have tried to call obsTargetEl.disconnect() before changeItem(); but changeItem() does not run after" - that could only happen if obsTargetEl.disconnect() throws an exception. Does it?
